# Spark streaming : Two Kafka stream join with time conditions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have two kafka stream, on stream has *event id* and the other stream has *event id* and *transaction id*.

One event id can have multiple transaction id.

I want to use spark streaming to keep sinking all the data to database from the second kafka topic (without any aggregation), but only for the event id from the first kafka topic and within 20 mins when we first get that event id from the first kafka topic.

I am wondering if there is any suggestion regarding how to do it in Spark Streaming.

Any comments or suggestions are much welcomed.

Comment: I feel like it'd be easier to do this in Kafka Streams / ksqlDB join methods, or maybe `faust` if using Python, but what have you tried so far in Spark?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I tried watermark, but seems it only works for the aggregation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you [edit] your question to include some code?